# What is the of method in java?

Tags: java

What is

```
import static java.util.stream.IntStream.of;
```

I saw it is used to find the sum of some numbers like this,

```
(array of numbers).sum()
```

what does it do ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#of-int...-

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download Java API Documentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521823/download-java-api-documentation)

Comment: What it does is make your code harder to read.  Some methods just shouldn't be static imported.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the of method in java?

There is no `of` method in Java.  But there is an `IntStream.of` method, and so on.  In fact there are roughly 100 *distinct* `of` methods in the Java 8 APIs.

> What is `import static java.util.stream.IntStream.of;` ?

It is a static import.

> what does it do?

The purpose is to allow this class to refer to the `static` method `IntStream.of` as `of` ... with no qualification.

Without it, you would need to write:

```
    of(<array of numbers>).sum()
```

as

```
    IntStream.of(<array of numbers>).sum()
```

However, the latter *would be* the better way to write this.  (IMO)  Especially considering how many different `of` methods there are.

---

@Louis Wasserman comments:

> What it does is make your code harder to read. Some methods just shouldn't be static imported.

I agree with that.  Some people are obsessed with conciseness at the expense of maintainability.  This is not an example that is good to copy.

Comment: Which would be a better practice anyway.

Comment: From the Oracle tutorial: ["So when should you use static import? Very sparingly!"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)

Answer (score 0):

Creates a new IntStream object with the integers you specify: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#of-int-

For future questions make sure you refer to the Java documentation, most of the information you need is there.

Comment: The advice about reading the javadocs is fine ... except that I think you missed the point of the question!

Answer (score 0):

This is equal to `IntStream.of(array of numbers).sum()`, which pipes the `array of numbers` into an `IntStream` and calls `sum` on the stream to evaluate the sum of its values by reduction.